# 1 Page site, change url and active nav depending on what part of the page you are at

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm messing around with trying to create a one page website, just to test it out.

Currently it is working so that clicking the nav links will scroll to certain part of pages, changes the url to include the id to page, and also changes the active tab css to active.

Though it is working when clicking on the nav menu buttons, I'm unable to get the url to change (eg, index.html > index.html#page1) and the active tab to apply active css style when scrolling through the page.

I've had a look around and can't get this to work.

```
<body>
<nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="top active">Top</li
        ><li class="page1">Menu1</li
        ><li class="page2">Menu2</li
        ><li class="page3">Menu3</li
        ><li class="page4">Menu4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="page1"></div>
    <div id="page2"></div>
    <div id="page3"></div>
    <div id="page4"></div>
</body>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav ul li").click(function(){
        var sectionId = $(this).attr('class')
        var sectionClass = $(this).attr('class')
        $('.active').removeClass('active');                                 /// Highlight on click
        $('.'+sectionClass).addClass('active');
        $('html, body').animate({                                           /// Scroll on click
            scrollTop: $("#"+sectionId).offset().top},'slow');
        window.location.href = "index.html" + "#" + sectionId;
    });

});
```

Comment: you are making it complex.

Comment: use liknking34's solution, it will append href of anchor tag in url automatically.

Comment: I realised I made this more complicated than it should have been, when using anchor I ran into a problem and found it easier doing it this way! I do have this working to change the url, though the problem I am having was not to do with this. I think I just wrote it confusingly. Currently the url and active tag css is working when im clicking on the tabs. What I am trying to do is get these to change as I am scrolling the page with the mouse, not with clicking on the tabs. Sorry for making this confusing!

Comment: you have to check when `window.scroll` event fires, check that which div is  in top position and make it active.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked you can change the URL in the HTML by using an `<a>` tag, you shouldn't need any JavaScript for it. Try this:

```
<nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="top active">Top</li>
        <li class="page1"><a href="#page1">Menu1</a></li>
        <li class="page2"><a href="#page2">Menu2</a></li>
        <li class="page3"><a href="#page3">Menu3</a></li>
        <li class="page4"><a href="#page4">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Of course you might need to change some of the CSS since you have an `<a>` tag now as well.

As for your CSS problem, I'd have to look at your site to know what's wrong.